# Android Custom Notification on Title Bar

Tags: android

Can any one please help me in designing notification that should show text on title bar. I attached screen shot,in that on title bar we can see 9KB/s. I need to show text like this only. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: This is notification icon.

Comment: But in that i need show data speed(numeric) dynamicaly. How can i??

Comment: by having many icons and updating notification with right one

Comment: Data speed may vary from 0 to 100. Then I need to have 101 different images. Do yo think is it good way. Or you do have any other idea.

Comment: There's no other way.

Comment: Actually I was exploring whether i can get any other soltion. But I couldn't get any. I agree with u. Still if u find any other better way pls guide me. Thanku u for response. :)